# Do I use the singular or plural form of a noun when describing an attribute of a plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

Take these two sentences for example:

> This is to compensate for the fluctuating **character** length in the sentence.

vs.

> This is to compensate for the fluctuating **characters** length in the sentence.

Which is correct? I would assume the latter but it sounds a bit awkward when spoken compared to the former.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for non-code, it messes with screen readers and is also unnecessary.

Comment: @AzorAhai Sorry, I figured the fixed font size would help people better see the very slight difference in the two.

Comment: No problem. I added bolding so it might be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> This is to compensate for the fluctuating **character** length in the sentence.

**character** in *character length* is a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier. So your options should really be *character length* and 
 *character lengths*.

However, in the given example, the sentence is one and the "character length," i.e., the length in number of characters is fluctuating. So you would have just "character length" as a property of the sentence. There's no need for a plural.

HTH.