# Must attributive nouns always be singular in form?

Tags: attributive-nouns

I want to speak in English that I have a list with car names. Should I say "cars list" or "car list"?

What if I have more than one attributive noun. Should all be singular?
For example I have two lists with commands. Each list has a different language and I want to merge them. Should I say

- *merged two different language commands lists* or
- *merged two different language command lists*?

Comment: Actually, I'd use *merged two language command lists*. Of course they are different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) The first thing you must realise is that not all modifier-of-noun words are adjectives. In _car list_, 'car' is a noun used attributively before the head noun 'list'. Adjectives in English are invariant for number, but occasionally, plural-form attributive nouns are used.

Comment: Related: [Countable Attributive nouns in plural context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478730/) and [Do I use the singular or plural form of a noun when describing an attribute of a plural noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456926/) and [Could the attributive noun be plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426413/) and [Singular/plural Nouns as Adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396864/), among others.